# error handling and search engines

Tags: apache, error-handling, seo

I have just changed my page structure from

eg

```
/my_page.php
```

to

```
/my_page/
```

but now all cached pages on search engines gives 404..

how can I handle them? is it possible to redirect all 404 to directly to the domain `www.domain.com` and in the same tiem send back a 301 redirect to the search engine?

Comment: `mod_rewrite` is the general solution to all your URL-rewriting needs. Your best bet is to rewrite `/my_page.php` to `/my_page/` (which should be easy enough to do, since its just replace .php with /)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following in htaccess (if available) or the virtual host's config:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*\.php$ /$1/[R=301,L]
```